# install different version of GCC side by side

Tags: fedora, gcc, shared-library, fortran

My primary problem is in my Fedora 28, `GCC8` is installed. Now, this gives `libgfortran.so.5`.

But many of my applications are not updated and still depends on `libgfortran.so.3`

So, how can I solve the problem? Is it safe to `ln libgf.so.5 to libgfso.3`?

Comment: You can install as many different versions of `gcc` as you want. The only thing that might come up is that you'll constantly have to change which ones you're using for different applications.

Comment: A workaround could be using Nix ( https://nixos.org/nix/ ) to manage the user specific programs.

Answer (score 2):

Linking the newer version to the older one *probably* won't work, because that number change usually reflects an ABI change.

The best approach for this is to run your older applications in containers — in this case, CentOS 7 has the version of libgfortran you are looking for, so a CentOS 7 container should provide you forward compatibility for a good long time.

Comment: He can give it a try. Worst case, it just won't work. The newer version of libraries such as `libgfortran` and `libstdc++` are normally backwards compatible. I create symlinks of older versions all the time.

Comment: @NasirRiley Eh, worst case it'll appear to work but then crash unexpectedly at a bad time.

Comment: That can indeed happen if there's something that's no longer supported or if it's built against something that requires something that's no longer supported. It's up to him to decided. If he just doesn't know then it's better that he just run it in a container as you've suggested where he can install a different version of `gcc` with different libraries.